# How to create modified copy of dataframe rows based on conditions in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, data-preprocessing

I have a `Pandas` dataframe which contains few columns and few rows.

```
    ColXYZ. Interval.  Temperature.  Pressure.  ColCDE.
A.    121       0            25           60        0.195
B.    246       4            40           50        0.350
C.    241       0            40           50        0.133
    ....
```

I would like to create duplicate values for each row whenever the `Interval` value is 0, and create this for all the `Temperature` and `Pressure` conditions in the dataset - e.g. create copy of row A with all value same except Temperature and Pressure changed, create duplicate for Row C with all values same except Temperature and Pressure changed. This is to reflect that at an Interval of 0, regardless of Temperature and Pressure, all other entries in the dataset rows remain same.
The desired output would be like:-

```
ColXYZ. Interval.  Temperature.  Pressure.  ColCDE.
121       0            25           60        0.195 #A
121       0            40           50        0.195 #Modified A copy
246       4            40           50        0.350 #B
241       0            40           50        0.133 #C
241       0            25           60        0.133 #Modified C copy
```

Any help and suggestions in this regard would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to change the temperature and pressure? Are they set at a fixed value? Some list you provide?

Comment: @kelyen I want all temperature and pressures in the dataset (they are fixed values) to reflect to this scenario.

Comment: What's the relation between a line with interval=0 and its copy?

Comment: @kelyen I want to create copies of those rows where interval is 0 for all combinations of temperature and pressure in the dataset. That is, only temperature and pressure would change in the new added rows, all other parameters would remain same.

Comment: yes, but how would they change?

Comment: @kelyen they shouldn’t change when Interval is 0. Everything remains same except temperature and pressure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most ideal way out is cross tab, see code below

```
  m=df['Interval.']==0



 new=(
    
        df[['Temperature.','Pressure.']]#Subset all temps
     
        .merge# cross merge to subset of dfs with interval=0

        (df[m].reset_index(),how='cross',suffixes = ('','_y')).drop_duplicates().drop(columns=['Temperature._y','Pressure._y'])# append back to subset of original df whose Interval was not 0

        .append(df[~m].reset_index())# sort values by index

        .sort_values(by=['index'])
    )
```

Outcome

```
   Temperature.  Pressure. index  ColXYZ.  Interval.  ColCDE.
0          25.0       60.0    A.    121.0        0.0    0.195
2          40.0       50.0    A.    121.0        0.0    0.195
0          40.0       50.0    B.    246.0        4.0    0.350
1          25.0       60.0    C.    241.0        0.0    0.133
3          40.0       50.0    C.    241.0        0.0    0.133
```

Alternative is to create repeat rows and insert as detailed below
Original df

```
    ColXYZ  Interval  Temperature  Pressure  ColCDE
A.     121         0           25        60   0.195
B.     246         4           40        50   0.350
C.     241         0           40        50   0.133
```

#Generate list of Temps and Pressures

```
df=df.reset_index()#to preserve index
m=df['Interval']==0#selection of soert criteria
s=df['Temperature'].agg(list)
s1=df['Pressure'].agg(list)
```

#Duplicate rows in df

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df[m].values, len(df), axis=0), columns=df.columns)
```

#distribute values of Temp and Pressure to ensure each unique value in original df is represented in each unique ColXYZ

```
df1['Temperature']= np.tile(s, int(len(df1)/(len(s))))
df1['Pressure']= np.tile(s1, int(len(df1)/(len(s1))))
```

#Drop duplicates

```
   df1= df[~m].append(df1.assign(Temperature=np.tile(s, int(len(df1)/(len(s)))),Pressure= np.tile(s1, int(len(df1)/(len(s1))))).drop_duplicates()).sort_values(by=['index'])
```

Outcome

```
   index ColXYZ Interval  Temperature  Pressure ColCDE
0    A.    121        0           25        60  0.195
1    A.    121        0           40        50  0.195
1    B.    246        4           40        50   0.35
3    C.    241        0           25        60  0.133
4    C.    241        0           40        50  0.133
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to clarify, I need to specify Interval as only 0 in first line of code you have mentioned? What does 0,2,1 mean please (I only want this to happen at Interval of 0) so i should check compatibility only at 0? Thanks

Comment: Perfect @wwnde thank you so much for the clarification !

Comment: I have a doubt - I want the repeats to be as many times as the number of different Temperature and Pressure combinations in the dataframe. I am confused as to what repeating twice does here please? Is it possible to make this dynamic, i.e. to adapt to creating repeats for all temperature and pressure combinations in the dataset whenever interval is 0.

Comment: Thank you @wwnde for your response. I tried to use this code but it doesn't seem to work as intended. I will clarify the logic to help you understand the question better if that helps - Imagine a Pandas dataframe df which has multiple columns, including columns named Interval, Temperature and Pressure. For all cases in the dataframe when Interval value == 0, I want to create duplicates of such rows for all Temperature and Pressure conditions in dataframe. Basically, to ensure that regardless of temperature and pressure varying in the dataset - all other values in rows remain same. Thanks.

Comment: This was a very good question. Thanks man. Will watch out for your posts. Happy coding